# How use native Windows Explorer instead of built in Intellij file browser

Tags: windows, android-studio, intellij-idea

The built in file browser is not easy to used especially in situation where a directory has a lot of subdirectories

Dropping and dragging is unnatural and not productive for me. Why do we need to use 2 tools for 1 job anyway? Isn't Windows Explorer alon already more than capable for that job?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ide.win.file.chooser.native=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart the IDE.

Note that you may have various issues with the native file chooser dialog and we don't recommend using it.

Comment: If using Linux, there is currently no such registry key. See [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-61486/Please-use-native-OS-File-Dialogs-in-IDEA#focus=Comments-27-8239974.0-0).